# Mechanize, python: Read a specific line from a site to reduce read.() time of long pages

Tags: python, mechanize, readline

I am using mechanize for python to read information.

Instead of reading the whole site as shown below, I'd like to access a specific line (e.g. line 439) from the site.

```
site = br.open('www.example.com').read()
```

The problem I have with the .read() is that some sites are too long and the process takes plenty of time to read. If there is a way to shorten reading time, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is not "line-oriented", but "tag/element-oriented".

Feed the mechanize's `response()` to the *HTML Parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [locate the tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())
print soup.find('my_tag', class_='my_class')
```